# Control the Remote Party ID header in Asterisk ARI

Tags: asterisk

I am oriingating a call using the asterisk py-ari library. However, I am unable to set the caller ID. The only caller ID the SIP provider accepts is the account username. Any other called ID is denied with SIP/2.0 603 Declined.

The provider has asked me to control the Remote Party ID header and place the caller ID there while the FROM header has the user (extension id).

How do I implement this in Asterisk ARI?

I am using Asterisk 16.2.1

Answer (score 0):

You should use SIPAddHeader application call.

Comment: The py-ari library does not make provision for that. The call is not controlled by the dial plan.

Comment: It do support execute which allow ANY application.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering how to go about it, update your SIP configuration file and set the parameters below for your channel.

fromuser=

sendrpid=yes

From the ARI point of view, you then set the caller ID in the same way as before.